# How can I tell iwd to prefer a network over another?

Tags: networking, wifi, configuration, iwd

I use [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd) as wireless deamon, and it automatically connects to available networks for which I've inserted the password in the past.

How can I instruct it to prefer a SSID over another when more than one is available?

From `man iwd.config` I understand that `[Rank]` ([see here](https://man.archlinux.org/man/iwd.config.5)) setting should serve this purpose, but I don't find an example of using it.